# reset Password not accepted

Tags: password

I reset my password in ubuntu 12.04. I got "password reset successfully" message.But when I try install/ unistall softwares, I get "worng pawwsord" message.

Why it is so?

Answer (score 1):

Do this in terminal

```
passwd
```

you can change the password for the account you are currently logged in

for changing other users password do

```
passwd <username>
```

the problem with yours maybe your caps lock was on or mistyped your password.

If unable to reset your password or lost it do the following:

1. Boot into recovery mode
2. then select 'root'
3. then enter command

   ```
   mount -o rw,remount /
   ```
4. then do

   ```
   passwd username
   ```

this resets the password for the specified account

if you have forgotten the username as well do

```
ls /home
```

and the list of users show up

reset the password by entering the above mentioned command

1. then enter

   ```
   exit
   ```

and select resume from the recovery options menu then ok